# Docker volume doesn't match `df` in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to mount a volume on a docker container, which is greater than 50G (the size of `dm.basesize`).

So I created a volume as the following:

```
docker volume create --driver local \
  --opt type=tmpfs --opt o=size=128G my_volume
```

The `docker volume inspect` shows:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2017-11-06T17:21:01+08:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/my_volume/_data",
        "Name": "my_volume",
        "Options": {
            "o": "size=128G",
            "type": "tmpfs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

And my **docker-compose.yml** defined as the following:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  myservice:
    build: myservice
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: my_volume
        target: /data
volumes:
  my_volume:
    external: true
```

But the `df -h` of **myservice** shows

```
Filesystem                Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root    50G  9.3G    41G   19%  /data
```

Which doesn't match the size I specified for the volume.

---

I have seen that I may modify the value of `dm.basesize`, but I don't want to make all the container's mount change.
Let said, I have 3 services that use three different docker volumes, and I want to customize 3 different size for them (all of them are greater than **50G**).

What did I do wrong? or am I misunderstood how docker volume work? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missig another option device. Check with [Driver-specific options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options)

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=tmpfs \
    --opt device=tmpfs \
    --opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 \
    foo
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Wondering why it didn't rings a warning if skipping the argument would make the volume unworkable.